# Why pointer to list create a 2D list structure

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I'm trying to implement a hashtable. I understand `list<int> *table` is a pointer to list(entries), and in the constructor, I init the size of the list(represents how many entries).
I'm very curious why this can be a list of list(2D list) structure, why I can perform

```
table[key].push_back(...);
```

Thanks

```
class HashTable {
private:
    int size;
    list<int> *table;
    
public:
    HashTable(int size);
    int hashFuntion(int x) {
        return x % size;
    };
    void insertItem(int x);
};

HashTable::HashTable(int size) {
    this->size = size;
    table = new list<int>[size];
}

void HashTable::insertItem(int x) {
    int key = hashFuntion(x);
    table[key].push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: It is not a list of list but an array of list. A list is not good at random accessing (like `table[key]`).

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for pointing out, but why this will become an array of list?   is "table = new list<int>[size]" create a array of list?

Comment: Why? It's a language design reason to represent arrays by a pointer to the first element. I'd recommend going with `std::vector<list<int>>` or `std::unique_ptr<list<int>[]>`. Alternativaly free the array in a destructor; you shouldn't want to leave this memory leak in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should learn how pointer work.

There are 'size' of list as you make in Initializer.

table[0], table[1] ... all of these are list.

Think about the case of int.

```
int* table = new int[size];
```

table[0], table[1] all of these are int.

```
list<int>* table = new list<int>[size];
```

then table[0], table[1] all of these are list.

A list is 1D structure. And you make a 1D structure with 1D structure.

Then 2D structure.